# Plotly.js: how to make markers only show when zoomed in (range slider with time on x-axis)

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using Plotly.js (javascript plotly) to configure a line chart that has a range slider and  has dates on the x-axis (as in [Range Slider and Selector | JavaScript | Plotly](https://plotly.com/javascript/range-slider/) and in the snippet below). When you zoom in, I want the line chart to have dots at each data point (aka, `mode: 'lines+markers'`). When you zoom out, the dots look too crowded because they are very close together. So, I want the dots to disappear ( `mode: 'lines'`) when zoomed in to 30 day's worth of data or less.

Is it possible to add markers to the chart only when zoomed in to a range span of 30 days or less? For example, when looking at an x-axis range of more than a week, the mode of the chart should be ‘lines’ but when zoomed in such that the x-axis’s range spans 30 days or less, the mode should be ‘lines+marker’.

I’m not certain the best language to ask the question, but I’m seeking a way to find a “hook” into the chart’s x-axis range. Since I’ve not defined the range (it’s managed instead via the range slider), how do I get my javascript to say “if the range[1] - range[0] is > 30 days, make mode = 'lines'; else if range[1] - range[0] is not > 30 days, make mode = 'lines+markers'.

```js
// Generate 500 random numbers for Y axis
var randoms = [375438,375436,375434,375430,375428,375428,375428,375428,375422,375413,375412,375408,375405,375405,375405,375403,375393,375383,375380,375373,375373,375373,375375,375374,375371,375371,375367,375367,375367,375364,375348,375330,375325,375324,375324,375324,375318,375301,375295,375276,375254,375254,375254,375251,375243,375225,375209,375203,375221,375221,375221,375205,375183,375172,375153,375153,375153,375147,375130,375114,375094,375083,375083,375083,375083,375067,375050,375028,375023,375023,375021,375027,375008,374992,374988,374967,374967,374967,374971,374955,374938,374921,374898,374898,374896,374893,374873,374861,374840,374828,374828,374835,374835,374827,374809,374798,374772,374773,374773,374773,374761,374748,374738,374738,374738,374738,374749,374749,374729,374718,374717,374717,374717,374713,374728,374714,374705,374697,374697,374697,374702,374682,374668,374654,374637,374636,374636,374637,374637,374637,374622,374622,374622,374622,374624,374611,374604,374597,374592,374592,374592,374597,374588,374582,374573,374579,374579,374579,374579,374579,374572,374576,374570,374570,374570,374570,374559,374559,374567,374546,374546,374546,374552,374542,374530,374527,374505,374505,374505,374486,374467,374451,374450,374439,374439,374439,374433,374422,374429,374424,374373,374373,374373,374376,374371,374371,374358,374350,374350,374350,374356,374340,374348,374341,374307,374307,374307,374311,374318,374299,374282,374272,374272,374272,374271,374265,374238,374234,374224,374224,374223,374215,374199,374180,374171,374171,374171,374171,374170,374175,374168,374089,374089,374089,374089,374089,374089,374089,374089,374089,374089,374089,374089,374089,374082,374102,374073,374073,374075,374105,374094,374076,374051,374051,374051,374043,374030,374021,374029,374029,374029,374029,374028,374008,373997,373994,373977,373977];
// Make an array 1 - 500 for X axis
var xrange =    ["2021-05-29","2021-05-28","2021-05-27","2021-05-26","2021-05-25","2021-05-24","2021-05-23","2021-05-22","2021-05-21","2021-05-20","2021-05-19","2021-05-18","2021-05-17","2021-05-16","2021-05-15","2021-05-14","2021-05-13","2021-05-12","2021-05-11","2021-05-10","2021-05-09","2021-05-08","2021-05-07","2021-05-06","2021-05-05","2021-05-04","2021-05-03","2021-05-02","2021-05-01","2021-04-30","2021-04-29","2021-04-28","2021-04-27","2021-04-26","2021-04-25","2021-04-24","2021-04-23","2021-04-22","2021-04-21","2021-04-20","2021-04-19","2021-04-18","2021-04-17","2021-04-16","2021-04-15","2021-04-14","2021-04-13","2021-04-12","2021-04-11","2021-04-10","2021-04-09","2021-04-08","2021-04-07","2021-04-06","2021-04-05","2021-04-04","2021-04-03","2021-04-02","2021-04-01","2021-03-31","2021-03-30","2021-03-29","2021-03-28","2021-03-27","2021-03-26","2021-03-25","2021-03-24","2021-03-23","2021-03-22","2021-03-21","2021-03-20","2021-03-19","2021-03-18","2021-03-17","2021-03-16","2021-03-15","2021-03-14","2021-03-13","2021-03-12","2021-03-11","2021-03-10","2021-03-09","2021-03-08","2021-03-07","2021-03-06","2021-03-05","2021-03-04","2021-03-03","2021-03-02","2021-03-01","2021-02-28","2021-02-27","2021-02-26","2021-02-25","2021-02-24","2021-02-23","2021-02-22","2021-02-21","2021-02-20","2021-02-19","2021-02-18","2021-02-17","2021-02-16","2021-02-15","2021-02-14","2021-02-13","2021-02-12","2021-02-11","2021-02-10","2021-02-09","2021-02-08","2021-02-07","2021-02-06","2021-02-05","2021-02-04","2021-02-03","2021-02-02","2021-02-01","2021-01-31","2021-01-30","2021-01-29","2021-01-28","2021-01-27","2021-01-26","2021-01-25","2021-01-24","2021-01-23","2021-01-22","2021-01-21","2021-01-20","2021-01-19","2021-01-18","2021-01-17","2021-01-16","2021-01-15","2021-01-14","2021-01-13","2021-01-12","2021-01-11","2021-01-10","2021-01-09","2021-01-08","2021-01-07","2021-01-06","2021-01-05","2021-01-04","2021-01-03","2021-01-02","2021-01-01","2020-12-31","2020-12-30","2020-12-29","2020-12-28","2020-12-27","2020-12-26","2020-12-25","2020-12-24","2020-12-23","2020-12-22","2020-12-21","2020-12-20","2020-12-19","2020-12-18","2020-12-17","2020-12-16","2020-12-15","2020-12-14","2020-12-13","2020-12-11","2020-12-10","2020-12-09","2020-12-08","2020-12-07","2020-12-06","2020-12-05","2020-12-04","2020-12-03","2020-12-02","2020-12-01","2020-11-16","2020-11-15","2020-11-14","2020-11-13","2020-11-12","2020-11-11","2020-11-10","2020-11-09","2020-11-08","2020-11-07","2020-11-06","2020-11-05","2020-11-04","2020-11-03","2020-11-02","2020-11-01","2020-10-31","2020-10-30","2020-10-29","2020-10-28","2020-10-27","2020-10-26","2020-10-25","2020-10-24","2020-10-23","2020-10-22","2020-10-21","2020-10-20","2020-10-19","2020-10-18","2020-10-17","2020-10-16","2020-10-15","2020-10-14","2020-10-13","2020-10-12","2020-10-11","2020-10-10","2020-10-09","2020-10-08","2020-10-07","2020-10-06","2020-10-05","2020-10-04","2020-10-03","2020-10-02","2020-10-01","2020-09-30","2020-09-29","2020-09-28","2020-09-27","2020-09-26","2020-09-25","2020-09-24","2020-09-23","2020-09-22","2020-09-21","2020-09-20","2020-09-19","2020-09-18","2020-09-17","2020-09-16","2020-09-15","2020-09-14","2020-09-13","2020-09-12","2020-09-11","2020-09-10","2020-09-09","2020-09-08","2020-09-07","2020-09-06","2020-09-05","2020-09-04","2020-09-03","2020-09-02","2020-09-01","2020-08-31"]

var trace = {
  x: xrange,
  y: randoms,
  mode: 'lines+markers'
};

var layout = {
  title: 'Time series with range slider and too many markers when zoomed out',
  height: 400,
  xaxis: {
      rangeslider: {}
  },
  yaxis: {
      fixedrange: true
  }
};

var data = [trace];


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<body>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!